# Check if a resource already exists with a different case

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In a wizard I am creating a package and trying to check if a resource already exists with a different case to avoid `ResourceException` thrown by `org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource#checkDoesNotExist`. For example I get this exception when I try to create a package com.Example.test while com.example.test already exist. So I would like to make a check for the every segment of the package name. The case for existing com.Example.test is already handled in my code.

Since the method `checkDoesNotExist` is in the internal class and not declared by `IResource` it's not in the public API and I cannot use it to make the check before calling `IFolder#create`. The method `IResource#exists` is useless in this case because it's case sensitive.

Currently I have the following solution:

```
/**
 * This method checks if a package or its part exists in the given source folder with a different case.
 * 
 * @param pfr A source folder where to look package in.
 * @param packageName Name of the package, e.g. "com.example.test"
 * @return A String containing path of the existing resource relative to the project, null if the package name has no conflicts.
 * @throws CoreException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String checkPackageDoesExistWithDifferentCase(IPackageFragmentRoot pfr, String packageName)
    throws CoreException, IOException
{
    IPath p = pfr.getResource().getLocation();
    String[] packagePathSegments = packageName.split("\\.");
    for (int i = 0; i < packagePathSegments.length; i++)
    {
        p = p.append(packagePathSegments[i]);
        File f = new File(p.toString());
        String canonicalPath = f.getCanonicalPath();
        if (f.exists() && !canonicalPath.equals(p.toOSString()))
            return canonicalPath.substring(pfr.getJavaProject().getResource().getLocation().toOSString().length() + 1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The issue about this solution is that it would work only on Windows, since `f.exists()` would return `false` on case-sensitive filesystems.

Comment: It is possible to check the ResourceException for that exact error without using internal methods

Comment: But then I would need to delete the created folder if the method succeeds, because I need only to check the existance for the validation on a wizard page, and it would be inefficient to do it after every typed character.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, there is not API, but you can check the parent resource if it has a member with the same (case-insensitive) name like this:

```
IContainer parent = newFolder.getParent();
IResource[] members = parent.members();
for( IResource resource : members ) {
  if( resource.getName().equalsIgnoreCase( newFolder.getName() ) ) {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The issue with this solution is that it cannot determine if a member exists with precisely the same name or its name has different case. Besides that I want to know this not just for the resource, but rather for its complete path. Please see the edited answer.